# One mistake with "subject_object_extraction" for working with spaCy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

I am use python3 with python shell in ubuntu. My code:

```
import spacy
from subject_object_extraction import findSVOs

# can still work even without punctuation
parse = parser("he and his brother shot me and my sister")
print(findSVOs(parse))

# very complex sample. Only some are correct. Some are missed.
parse = parser("... any text ... ")
print(findSVOs(parse))
```

As result, I have the next mistake:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vv/PythProj/sp_ex_2.py", line 2, in <module>
from subject_object_extraction import findSVOs
ImportError: No module named 'subject_object_extraction'
```

Where is my mistake? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The module subject_object_extraction isn't a part of the spaCy package, it's written by Schrading himself, and can be found here: https://github.com/NSchrading/intro-spacy-nlp/blob/master/subject_object_extraction.py

From https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/493

Comment: Thank you for your help!